# Why would increasing troop production prolong the war?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

I'm watching Star Wars: The Clone Wars ([Season 2, Episode 15](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-wars-the-clone-wars&episode=s02e15)), and I just heard something that just doesn't make much sense to me.

> Senator Padmé Amidala, recognizing
>   that more troops will only prolong
>   the fighting, works tirelessly with
>   her allies to introduce a bill to
>   cut down military spending and stop
>   the creation of more clone troopers…

I don't understand her position.  Why would increasing production draw out the war?  I mean, I can accept that stopping production would mean the war would effectively end -- with the Good Guys losing.  But how is decreasing production a sound military strategy?

Comment: "a group of senators lead by **Halle Burtoni** of Comino propose an escalation of troop production". HalleBurtoni? I mean, seriously, Lucas...*<shakes heads>*

Comment: @Richard - Lucas trying to make nice with liberals after Jar Jar Binks and Watto racism accusations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Padmé's position is made eminently clear in the [Revenge of the Sith](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html), she despises the war and doesn't trust the Chancellor any farther than she can throw him;

> **PADME:** *What if the democracy we thought we were serving no longer exists, and the Republic has become the very evil we have been
>   fighting to destroy?*
>
> **ANAKIN:** *I don't believe that. And you're sounding like a Separatist!*
>
> **PADME:** ***Anakin, this war represents a failure to listen . . . Now, you're closer to the Chancellor than anyone. Please, please ask
>   him to stop the fighting and let diplomacy resume.***

In her opinion, producing more clones will simply result in the Federation producing more battle droids which will in turn lead to billions more civilian casualties **on both sides**.

Comment: After all, she doesn't condone courses of action that lead to war.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald - Precisely this.